# How do I pick random data from an array and make sure that a minimum of a certain data are selected from that array without effecting probability?

Tags: javascript

I am selecting randomly 20 bikes from a larger array of bikes, and then creating a new array with those selected bikes. I would like to make sure that at least 2 of the randomly selected bikes in that new array are the color red. More than 2 can be red, but at a minimum 2 should be. How is this achieved while making it fair to all of the randomly selected bikes?

Some example code:

```
const bikes = [
  { type: 'bmx', color: 'red' },
  { type: 'mountain', color: 'blue' },
  { type: 'bmx', color: 'yellow' },
  { type: 'mountain', color: 'black' },
  { type: 'bmx', color: 'red' },
  { type: 'bmx', color: 'purple' }
  ...more bikes
]

const getRandomBikes = () => {
  const randomBikes = []

//random select 20 bikes
    for(let i = 0; i < 20; i++) { 
        randomBikes.push(bikes[Math.floor(Math.random() * bikes.length)])
   }

  return randomBikes
}

getRandomBikes()
```

So pretty simple to return a random array. But now how would I make sure that the random bike array contained ***at least*** two bikes with `color: 'red'` without effecting the probability of every bike being selected? Presumably I would be running `getRandomBikes()` until the returned array satisfied the requirements, but say my array of `bikes` is `10000` long, that may take forever before the requirement is met. How do I ensure at least two red bikes end up in the randomly selected bike array?

Answer (score 3):

While iterating, you might count up the number of required bikes of a specific color remaining, and if equal to the number of items that remain to be chosen, pick only from the bikes with the right color.

```js
const bikes = [
  { type: 'bmx', color: 'red' },
  { type: 'mountain', color: 'blue' },
  { type: 'bmx', color: 'yellow' },
  { type: 'mountain', color: 'black' },
  { type: 'bmx', color: 'red' },
  { type: 'bmx', color: 'purple' }
];

const getRandomBikes = (requiredRed, totalPicks) => {
  const chosenBikes = [];
  const reds = bikes.filter(({ color }) => color === 'red');
  for(let i = 0; i < totalPicks; i++) {
    const redsSoFar = chosenBikes.reduce((a, b) => a + (b.color === 'red'), 0);
    const picksRemaining = totalPicks - i;
    const mustChooseRed = requiredRed - redsSoFar === picksRemaining;
    chosenBikes.push(
       mustChooseRed
       ? reds[Math.floor(Math.random() * reds.length)]
       : bikes[Math.floor(Math.random() * bikes.length)]
    );
  }
  return chosenBikes;
}

console.log(getRandomBikes(2, 3));
```

Or with less complexity

```js
const bikes = [
  { type: 'bmx', color: 'red' },
  { type: 'mountain', color: 'blue' },
  { type: 'bmx', color: 'yellow' },
  { type: 'mountain', color: 'black' },
  { type: 'bmx', color: 'red' },
  { type: 'bmx', color: 'purple' }
];

const getRandomBikes = (requiredRed, totalPicks) => {
  const chosenBikes = [];
  const reds = bikes.filter(({ color }) => color === 'red');
  let redsSoFar = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < totalPicks; i++) {
    const picksRemaining = totalPicks - i;
    const mustChooseRed = requiredRed - redsSoFar === picksRemaining;
    const chosenBike = mustChooseRed
       ? reds[Math.floor(Math.random() * reds.length)]
       : bikes[Math.floor(Math.random() * bikes.length)]
    if (chosenBike.color === 'red') redsSoFar++;
    chosenBikes.push(chosenBike);
  }
  return chosenBikes;
}

console.log(getRandomBikes(2, 3));
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this, this makes a lot of sense! I have one question though: what is the purpose of this? I get that is letting the function know to choose red or not, but why is this comparison made against the remaining picks? `const mustChooseRed = requiredRed - redsSoFar === picksRemaining;` ?